# Bundle NPM Package so it has different import paths with Vite and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, vite

How can I bundle my NPM package in a way that I can have different import paths for different parts of the package? I have found webpack approaches, but I am using Vite and TS.

My package looks like this:

```
- src
  - atoms
  - molecules
  - organism
  - index.ts (currently simply imports and exports everything)
```

Now I can use this currently like this

```js
import { Button } from '@mypackage/library'
```

How can I do it, so I get this outcome:

```js
import { Button } from '@mypackage/library/atom'
```

Here is the relevant part of my package.json

```json
{
  "entry": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./atoms": "./src/atoms/index.ts",
    "./molecules": "./src/molecules/index.ts",
    "./organisms": "./src/organisms/index.ts",
    "./theme": "./src/theme/index.ts"
  },
}
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      name: '@workdigtital/component-library-react',
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
        },
        exports: 'named'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [react(), dts({ insertTypesEntry: true })],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  }
});
```

If I currently try an import like this, inside another project (Laravel+React), in which installed the library.

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@workdigital/component-library-react/theme';
```

I get the following run time error (But no Typescript errors, even IntelliSense is working):

```
Failed to load url /resources/js/theme/ThemeProvider (resolved id: /resources/js/theme/ThemeProvider). Does the file exist?
```

My resulting Dist folder looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't have TypeScript `exports`, this simply won't work. An `npm` package should have only JS exports.

If you want to be able to selectively import different parts of your package, you must transpile them to different files.

`rollup` can do it, but it is lots of work, as you will have to set up a separate target for each exported file. Normally you use `rollup` to create a single bundle, this what this tool is made for.

`tsc` with a `tsconfig.json` will be a much better choice in your case. It does this by default, you only need to specify the output directory and it will produce a separate file for each source.

There is an excellent guide on the TypeScript site about packaging TypeScript libraries, you should probably start there.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers - it is a TypeScript library published with `tsc` that has what you are trying to do - check the `tsconfig.json` and the `package.json`